# Prove that $a^b \times a^c = a^{b+c}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that $a^b \times a^c = a^{b+c}$ for any natural numbers $a,b,c$.

Let $A,B,C$ be sets, and each set has cardinality $a,b,c$, respectively. I know from the previous exercise that $\#((A^B) \times (A^C)) = a^b\times a^c$, and $\#(A^{B\cup C}) = a^{b+c}$ assuming that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Therefore, we need to find bijection from one set to another set to show that these two have the same cardinality.

First, we have the set $\{(f,g) | f: B \to A, g: C \to A\}$, and $\{h | h: B\cup C \to A\}$. Define $\varphi: (A^B) \times (A^C) \to A^{B\cup C}$ to be $\varphi(f, g) = h$.

Now the task is to prove that $\varphi$ is a bijection, but I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't defined $\varphi$.

Comment: I don't see any real analysis in your question. Why did you add that tag?

Comment: @celtschk This question comes from Exercise 3.6.6 in Analysis 1 by Tao. But, if you think it is irrelevant, you can edit it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "definition" of $\phi$ is vague and not a definition; $\phi(f,g)=h$ OK, but what *is* $h$? You don't tell us.

So make it concrete first: we're given $f \in A^B$ and $g \in A^C$ now **define** a function on $B \cup C$ as follows:

$$\phi(f,g)(x)=\begin{cases} f(x) & x \in B\\
                          g(x) & x \in C\\
            \end{cases}
$$

which is well defined (any $x \in B \cup C$ lies in exactly one of the sets $B$ or $C$, and all values of $f,g$ lie in $A$, so $\phi(f,g)$ also has values in $A$.
So $\phi(f,g) \in A^{B \cup C}$

$\phi$ is injective, because if $\phi(f,g) = \phi(f',g')$ also $f=\phi(f,g)\restriction_B = \phi(f',g')\restriction_B=f'$ and likewise $g=g'$ by restricting to $C$, so $(f,g)=(f',g')$ as pairs as well.

$\phi$ is surjective: when $h \in A^{B \cup C}$ we can easily see that $\phi(h\restriction_B, h\restriction_C)=h$ because they agree on all points of $B \cup C$.

So the $\phi$ I defined is a bijection between the sets $A^B \times A^C$ and $A^{B \cup C}$. Note that finiteness plays no rôle here. This holds for all sets $A,B,C$.

Answer (score 2):

Without defining $\varphi$ first, you cannot possibly prove that it is bijective.

Now, define $\varphi(f,g)$ as the map $h\colon B\cup C\longrightarrow A$ such that $h|_B=f$ and that $h|_C=g$ (at this point, the fact that $B\cap C=\emptyset$ is essential). Then $\varphi$ is indeed a bijection. For instance, it has an inverse: the map $\psi$ defined by $\psi(h)=(h|_A,h|_B)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can show $\varphi$ is injective, but I am not sure how to show that it is surjective. How can we guarantee that there exits $f,g$ for each $h \in A^{B\cup C}$?

Comment: Since it has an inverse, it is bijective and, in particular, it is injective. Or, given $h$, you can take $f=h|_B$ and $g=h|_C$.